# In OpenGL ES2.0 for iOs, how can I use a CVPixelBufferRef to update a cubemap texture?

Tags: ios5, opengl-es, ios6, opengl-es-2.0

I have managed to get a CVPixelBufferRef from an AVPlayer to feed pixel data that I can use to texture a 2D object. When my pixelbuffer has data in it I do:

```
CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage('
kCFAllocatorDefault,
  videoTextureCache_,
  pixelBuffer, //this is a CVPixelBufferRef
  NULL,
  GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
  GL_RGBA,
  frameWidth,
  frameHeight,
  GL_BGRA,
  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  0,
  &texture);
```

I would like to use this buffer to create a GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP. My video frame data is actually 6 sections in one image (e.g. a cubestrip) that in total makes the sides of a cube. Any thoughts on a way to do this?

I had thought to just pretend my  GL_TEXTURE_2D was a GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP and replace the texture on my skybox with the texture generated by the code above, but this creates a distorted mess (as I suppose should be expected when trying to force a skybox to be textured with a GL_TEXTURE_2D.

The other idea was to setup unpacking using glPixelStorei and then read from the pixelbuffur:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, width);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, X);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, Y);
glTexImage2D(...,&pixelbuffer);
```

But unbelievably GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH is not supported in OpenGl ES2.0 for iOS.

So, is there:

-Any way to split us the pixel data in my CVPixelBufferRef through indexing the buffer to some pixel subset before using it to make a texture?

-Any way to make a 6 new GL_TEXTURE_2D as indexed subsets of my GL_TEXTURE_2D that is created by the code above

-any way to convert a GL_TEXTURE_2D to a valid GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP (e.g. GLKit has a Skybox effect that loads a GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP from a single cubestrip file. It doesnt have a method to load a texture from memory though or I would be sorted)

-any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If it were impossible any other way (which is unlikely, there probably is an alternate way -- so this is probably not the best answer & involves more work than necessary) here is a hack I'd try:

How a cube map works is it projects the texture for each face from a point in the center of the geometry out toward each of the cube faces. So you could reproduce that behavior yourself; you could use Projective Texturing to make six draw calls, one for each face of your cube. Each time, you'd first draw the face you're interested in to the stencil buffer, then calculate the projection matrix for your texture (this technique is used a lot for 'spotlight' effects in games), then figure out the transform matrix required to augment the fragment shader's texture read so that for each face, only the portion of the texture that corresponds to that face winds up within the (0..1) texture lookup range. If everything has gone right, anything outside the 0..1 range should be discarded by the stencil buffer, and you'd be left with a DIY cube map out of a TEXTURE_2D.

The above method is actually really similar to what I'm doing for an app right now, except I'm only using projective texturing to mask off & replace a small portion of the cube map. I need to pixel-match the edges of the small square I'm projecting so that it's seamlessly applied to the skybox, so that's why I feel confident that this method will actually reproduce the cube map behavior -- otherwise, pixel-matching wouldn't be possible.

Anyway, I hope you find a way to simply transition your 2D to CUBEMAP, because that would probably be much easier and cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Your suggestion sounds technically feasible. I am going to try a few other things including treating the pixelbuffer as a texture atlas and possibly just writing a custom shader to map the single image to the cube.

Comment: I think that's essentially my suggestion; minus the projective texturing bit. Anyway as I think about it, I'm not sure if projective texturing would be required or not to get a cube map effect. I've got a hunch it will, but am not experienced enough to say for sure without prototyping it. I feel like there ought to be a better way to juggle the data to leave you with a proper cube map though, but sadly I'm no help there.